# Why would child node animation turn a parent div's background into random colored noise?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have a modal div with absolute positioning that pops up over a game when the user has one.  It uses css-animation to grow in width and height to it's final position.  This modal div uses `display: grid` with two rows, one for header divs and another for content.

Once the modal-show animation is completed is calls a function that fills in the header and content rows programmatically.  The process is that the content div is created, given the appropriate id to be styled with css, and filled with a string of html defining a simple svg element with a path and text.

```
function win_modal_content() {
    game.modal_state = game.modals.WIN;
    modal_header('Winner!')

    // content goes here 
    let content = div('modal_content');
    content.innerHTML = `
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="win_star" fill="yellow">
    <path d="M 50,36.4 63.8,23.5 66,43 84,42, 74,54 82,66 65,64 64,80 50,67 36,80 34,63 17,68 26,52 19,37.4 35,37 37.2,18.9 z">
    </g>
    <text id="win_text" x="50" y="50" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12.5px" font-weight="bold" fill="red">${game.answer}</text>
    </svg>
    `;
    divs.modal.appendChild(content);
}
```

This works great and everything is fine, until I try to animate the path and text colors (just showing the path animation, the text one is very similar):

```
#win_star {
    animation-name: win-star;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes win-star {
    0% {
        stroke: yellow;
        fill: red;
    }

    50% {
        stroke: red;
        fill: yellow;
    }

    100% {
        stroke: yellow;
        fill: red;
    }
}
```

This works very well and I was very happy to see it working until I tested it on my mobile.  I am using Iphone8+ with IOS15.3 and get some very unusual results.  Instead of the standard black background, the modal div slowly reveals a bunch of random colored pixel noise that isn't moving, but shows up gradually (opacity increases from 0 to 1).

I have tried to bypass the original modal animation, turn on and off different parts of the animations of the text and paths.  Wrap things in svg groups and animate those.  And finally, I tried to hard code the html for the svg and modal, but it's always the same thing.  Random colored pixel noise (tiled and static, not moving).

I also spent time in the inspector looking to see if extra elements were being generated somewhere but everything looked normal.

One thing that is promising is that the exact same behavior happens on both Safari and Chrome.  Basically that whole screen should be black except for the star, title, x-button, and border.

[image: Random Noise]

Any help would certainly be appreciated!

Comment: Could you make your code into a snippet and ensure it shows the problem as I can’t make the code you have given go wrong in the way you describe on IOS 15 Safari. And could you describe more what you mean by standard black background as my system gives a white background with the given code.

Comment: I made an html file with the css and script embedded to recreate the problem.  Of course when I test his, the problem went away.  I just finished refactoring the original code and it works great.  I still wish I knew what the issue was, but I have to move on.  Thank you for your reply @AHaworth it's appreciated.